# How to combine itertools.product and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-itertools

In the algorithm I have a main loop in the form:

```
for i in itertools.product(range(2), repeat=4): 
    # do something on"i"
```

The results from the whole loop arise recursively. This means that the result from the first step affects the result of the second step, the result from the second step affects the result of the third step, and so on. Can multiprocessing be used with such an algorithm construction?

Comment: Your question seems very general to me. I'm not clever enough to answer it in that generality. Can you be more specific about what might occur in the first step, the second step, the third, and so on?

Comment: in general, a list of some output results from each step is enlarged at each step. while inside a loop, the result from a given step depends on the content in this list from the previous steps. therefore, the order in which steps are taken after the "i" variable is important. and I have doubts whether multiprocessing can be used with such a construction. my question is also related to the entry for `codereview`: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185129/157474. I have already lost some hope that I will solve this problem.